# React Native (Expo managed) - Asset.LocalUri returns null in Android production

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I would like to allow users to share an image (local asset, known at build time) using expo-sharing library. For this, I follow this approach:

```
/** Typing for local assets in components/icons/index.ts file */
export const icons = {
   badges: {
      badge: require('./badge.png')
   }
}
```

```
/** 
 * Load asset. In original code, I have multiple badges, 
 * so I use 'useAssets' from 'expo-asset' library to load them all at once 
*/
const [assets, assetError] = useAssets(icons.badges.badge) 

/** Share badge using social platforms */
const shareBadge = async () => {
   const badge = assets[0];
   const loadedBadge = await badge.downloadAsync() // I only added this line to try to solve the issue as written in documentation, but it didn't help
   await Sharing.shareAsync( loadedBadge.localUri, {
      UTI: 'public.png',
      mimeType: 'image/png',
      dialogTitle: 'Share Badge',
   }
}
```

Provided code is tested and works on following environments: `Expo Go iOS`, `Expo Go Android`, `Web (dev env)`, `Production iOS`. `Production Android` is the only environment that is not working (which makes it extremely hard to fix this, as I need to build the app and upload it to the phone to replicate).

Using Sentry, I was able to catch exception thrown in `shareBadge` method:

```
Error: Only local file URLs are supported (expected scheme to be 'file', got 'null'.
```

From caught exception, I assume that the problem is that badge.localUri returns `null` instead of `file://path/to/file.png`. This is strange for two reasons:

1. I am using these files in other part of code as props in `<Image src={imageAsset} />` without any problem
2. It works in iOS builds (even in production) and Expo Go Android
   So I assume the code can't be completely wrong.

I am on `Expo 46`, using EAS build

Answer (score 0):

In the [expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/#useassetsmoduleids) they verify the asset exist before using it:

```js
const [assets, error] = useAssets([
  require('path/to/asset.jpg'),
  require('path/to/other.png')
]);
return assets ? <Image source={assets[0]} /> : null;
```

I think your issue is that you aren't checking to verify that the assets are loaded. This should be causing issues on all platforms; but its likely that the all devices you are testing on except Android are loading the assets faster than you can call the `shareBadge`. You could do something like this:

```js
const shareBadge = async () => {
   if(!assets || assetError){
     return
   }
   const badge = assets[0];
   
   const loadedBadge = await badge.downloadAsync() // I only added this line to try to solve the issue as written in documentation, but it didn't help
   await Sharing.shareAsync( loadedBadge.localUri, {
      UTI: 'public.png',
      mimeType: 'image/png',
      dialogTitle: 'Share Badge',
   }
}
```

but it would be awkward to have a ShareBadge button that could possibly do nothing, so I'd suggest having a state variable tied to whether the assets are loaded:

```js
const [assets, assetError] = useAssets(icons.badges.badge);
const [assetsIsLoaded, setAssetsIsLoaded = useState(false);

// listen for assets changes, or assetError
useEffect(()=>{
  if(assetError){
    // log error or something
  }
  else
    setAssetsIsLoaded(assets && assets.length > 0)
},[assets,assetError])
```

With a state variable tied to the assets status you have more UI options, such as disabling the Share Badge button until assets is loaded, or maybe having a loading animation.